# Can you mirror an iPad to a TV via HDMI adapter while iPad is locked?

Tags: ipad, hdmi, lightning

I have an iPad connected to an HDTV using the [Apple Lightning Digital AV Adapter] (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD826ZM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter). When the iPad is on everything works nominally: the iPad screen is mirrored to the TV.

Is there a way to continue to push the screen contents when the iPad is locked or smart cover closed? I don't need to see what's on the iPad, I'm basically just using it as a projector.

I know airplay will continue video playback when a cover is closed (at least in some apps). I'm trying to do the same thing over the Digital AV Adapter cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings screen within the "General" tab is an "Lock/Unlock" Boolean that controls whether the device sleeps when the screen cover is closed. Turning this off will maintain the screen contents when the iPad is locked or smart cover closed, but it means the device screen is on until the auto sleep timer triggers.